# AttributeError in tkinter gui programming

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display my calculated output in a Gui window in python. I am trying with Tkinter. But I'm having problems displaying the output on Tkinter level widget. I am putting input data as address information in text field of Tkinter window and want latitude, longitude of that inputed address to the text label. Can anyone please help me out of this? I am just quite new to this Tkinter.

code is below:

```
def initialize(self):
    self.grid()

    self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self)
    self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')

    button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Get Geo information !",command=self.OnButtonClick)
    button.grid(column=1,row=0)

    self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()

    label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,
                          anchor="w",fg="black",bg="white")
    label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')

    self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.resizable(True,False)


def OnButtonClick(self):
    outf = open(out_file,'w')
    outf_failed = open(out_file_failed,'w')
    #inf = open(addr_file,'r')
    inf = codecs.open(addr_file, 'r', 'iso-8859-1')

    for address in inf:
        #get latitude and longitude of address
        data = geocode(address)

        #output results and log to file

         if len(data)>1:

             self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (Latitude )", data['lat'] )
             self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (Longitude )", data['lng'] )

             outf.write(address.strip()+data['lat']+','+data['lng']+'\n')
                    outf.flush()
         else:
             self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" Geocoding of '"+addr_file+"' failed with error code "+data['code'] )

             outf_failed.write(address)

             outf_failed.flush()

         time.sleep(sleep_time)

    #clean up
    inf.close()
    outf.close()
    outf_failed.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('Your Location')
    app.mainloop()
```

And I got error:

```
File "F:\JavaWorkspace\Test\src\gui_geo_location.py", line 94, in OnButtonClick
    self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (Latitude )", data['lat'] )
  File "C:\Python25\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1721, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: entryVariable
```

Here is my `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)

        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Get Geo information !",command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()

        label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,
                              anchor="w",fg="black",bg="white")
        label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 94 in `F:\JavaWorkspace\Test\src\gui_geo_location.py`, you're using `self.entryVariable` but that object does not have an `entryVariable` attribute.

Based on your `__init__`, it seems you haven't defined `entryVariable` anywhere. Try adding:

```
self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
```

to your `__init__` method. See [this page](http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/) for more information.

Comment: Hi..I attached my __init() method .. but couldnt figure it out the problem!..:(